# Entity Framework Bulk Updates

Tags: performance, entity-framework, sql-update, bulk

I'm currently using EF5 and I have an entity InvoinceGroup which is related to many Invoices. Each Invoice is also related to many Practices.
When I want to pay an invoice, I need to know only que practices with a certain status (L).
These L practices, which were originaly related to the invoice 0, need to move to another invoice that is created on the fly, and each invoice is different depending on the customer. In addition to that, these new created invoices will have belong to one InvoiceGroup.

I need to perform a bulk update to the practices changing from the 0 invoice to the newly created invoice and the problem is that I have close to 5000 practices per invoice and above 100 invoices in each group.
It takes a very long time to do this and I assume that EF updates it one by one.
I've planned to do this by an sp, but my question is: Is there a better way to do this only using EF?

Answer (score 0):

No, EF will only do INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs one-by-one.

You can create an SP, and either execute it directly, or import it into your EF model and execute it from there.  Either way, you can't do the type of bulk operation you describe using only the Entity Framework.